# Search repeated Chinese chracters in a plain text with regex?

Tags: regex, unicode, textmate

First i know match chinese unicode should use

```
[\x{4e00}-\x{9fa5}]
```

Then i use group and backreference

```
([\x{4e00}-\x{9fa5}])\1
```

But the result is adjacency, like "中中".

I need **all the character which appear more than one time** anywhere in the text.
Like

```
中国保持中立
^      ^
```

PS.I use textmate editor.

Any help? TIA!

Comment: Don't know about textmate, but will `([\x{4e00}-\x{9fa5}]).*\1` help?

Comment: Do not work as expect :<

Comment: @Maadiah, what did you expect?

Comment: @Maadiah Huh, it works in JS (in form `([\u4e00-\u9fa5]).*\1`). Also sorry for the edit, as SO's editor seems a little misleading.

Comment: sorry for my bad english.There are too many result when use `([\x{4e00}-\x{9fa5}]).*\1` [Picture](https://www.dropbox.com/s/30colhf0drgpg2u/%E5%B1%8F%E5%B9%95%E5%BF%AB%E7%85%A7%202013-02-27%20%E4%B8%8B%E5%8D%884.15.06.png)

Comment: @Maadiah, why are there too many results? All your matches start and end with the same character, so it found correctly characters that occur more than once.

Comment: @Maadiah The result in the screenshot is exactly what you asked for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

1. Match everything till the last occurrence of that character

   ```
   ([\x{4e00}-\x{9fa5}]).*\1
   ```

   See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?33u82)
2. Match everything till the next occurrence of that character

   ```
   ([\x{4e00}-\x{9fa5}]).*?\1
   ```

   See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?33u7s)
3. If you want to match only a character that is occurring also later on in the text and you don't want match everything in between and **if [lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) are supported**

   ```
   ([\x{4e00}-\x{9fa5}])(?=.*\1)
   ```

   See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?33u88)

   This will not match the last occurrence! (Because the character is not following anymore in the text.)

Comment: (Your answer is OK, just some side comment). According to [this](http://manual.macromates.com/en/regular_expressions), TextMate uses Oniguruma regular expression library, while RegExr uses Flex 3 flavor. It happens that the features are overlapping, especially `\x{hhhh}`, since the documentation for [Flex 3 regex](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=12_Using_Regular_Expressions_03.html) doesn't say anything about it, and `\uhhhh` is supposed to work but doesn't work in Flex 3.

Comment: @nhahtdh, I like Regexr for the user interface, but the behaviour is a bit inconsistent. It seems to support more than it should. e.g. I know that Regexr is supporting fixed length **lookbehind**, but in the Flex3 documentation only lookahead is mentioned.